# c++ eof and failbit in the middle of reading binary file

Tags: c++, io

I have troubles reading a binary file. It seems it does not read up to its end:

```
// get file size
ifs.open (inFile.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::ate);
cout << "file size:  " << ifs.tellg() << endl;;
ifs.close();

// read file
ifs.open (inFile.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
int counter = 0;
char c = 0;
for (counter = 0; ifs; ++counter)
    ifs >> c;

cout << "last char:  " << int(c) << endl;
cout << "read bytes: " << counter << endl;
cout << "fail? " << (ifs.fail() ? "yes" : "no") << endl;
cout << "bad?  " << (ifs.bad() ? "yes" : "no") << endl;
cout << "eof?  " << (ifs.eof() ? "yes" : "no") << endl;
ifs.close();
```

Below is the output. I don't understand why I get that `eofbit` in the middle of a file and why it comes together with the `failbit`:

```
file size:  289384
last char:  1
read bytes: 288598
fail? yes
bad?  no
eof?  yes
```

I get that on Unix system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a test and discovered the problem. It's obvious once you add `ofs << c` to the for loop.

It is not reading white-space.

You can fix this by either adding `#include <iomanip>` and `ifs >> noskipws`, or by using binary input functions like `ifs.get(c)`

Comment: Oh gosh, thanks a lot! That thing was driving me crazy.